# How to handle OnTimer event in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

I need to show a message say "Hi" everyday at 9 AM. Do I require Timer for this? How can I check whether its 9 AM or not. What should be the interval of timer at which `OnTimer` event  run?

```
procedure Form1.TimerTimer1(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage("Hi");
end;
```

If I run this event in after 24 hours, I fear it might pass 9 AM and will not fire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have other valid reasons, it's far more easier to

- write a simple application that shows the message and quits
- schedule it to run using the task scheduler of Windows

[image]

Comment: "There were no search results found" - I got this error when I type "sched task" to open task scheduler. How to resolve it?

Comment: @NareshKumar - As you already flagged this as the answer, I assume you found the task scheduler?

Comment: And when the Conficker virus (or it's clones) hit your client - the Admins disable all scheduled tasks - then what? Relying on Task Manager is not good practice, believe me - my practice confirms this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CRON like solutions for Delphi: http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cron-scheduler/

Comment: If you do, in fact, need to keep your programming running, using a cron like scheduler would work.  The code from the above link works well.

Comment: Yeah, better implement it as a service

Answer (score 1):

As the answerers before me said, there are better and easier ways. Suppose you want to do this your way, in Delphi, then yes, you need a timer. The needed steps are:

1. Put the timer on your form;
2. Set the "interval" property to 1000 (one second) or less. For greater precision, you can set the interval property to 1, and the program will do the checking each milisecond
3. Write the handler for OnTimer:

   ```
   procedure Form1.TimerTimer1(Sender: TObject);
   var x:TDateTime
   begin
   x:=Now;
   if {the hour read is 9 and minute is 0} then
   ShowMessage("Hi");
   end;
   ```

Hope it helps.